# Why would any DLL being injected crash a host process?

Tags: windows, access-violation, dll-injection

In beta testing a new release of my software, several users reported exceptions when running the app. In both cases it's: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)". I've also seen it as 0xc0000005.  I found a local system with this error as well and found when running it under a debugger, "datamngr.dll" had an access violation and failed allocating on the heap.  I quickly discovered "datamngr.dll" is spyware and is being loaded as it was in the system's AppInit.

Once I cleared the AppInit reg key, this problem went away.  I checked it out via Process Monitor, and any time this DLL was being injected, my application crashed.  I thought it was just badly written spyware, but I've since found other DLLs doing the same thing (such as acaptuser32.dll, which is legitimate software).  What's odd to me is the previous version of my software does not crash.  There's been many, many changes between the two versions so it's hard to say what it is.

Where do I start here?  Some online exploring shows apps like Firefox replace LoadLibrary to blacklist DLLs from being injected.  But I'd like to start from the more basic -- why is the application now crashing when it didn't before?

I realize this is very vague, but that's pretty much unavoidable.  I'm hoping there's something obvious in the properties for the project I'm doing incorrectly.  I've tried with ASLR on and off, DEP on and off...I've tried delay-loading user32.dll and manually loading it via LoadLibrary (with SetErrorMode set to ignore errors), and nothing is working for me.  We've seen this happen on Windows XP and Windows 7 (32 and 64-bit).

Any pointers on where to start would be greatly appreciated.  I'll provide as much information as I can if anyone needs other details.

Cheers

Comment: [You are pretty much boned](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/13/6648400.aspx)

Comment: Do you have some sort of version control?  The most obvious troubleshooting measure would be to identify the exact point at which the behaviour changed - although personally I'd start by rebuilding the previous version from source in case it's a change in your build tools rather than in the application source itself.

Comment: Does the program crash before or after entering your application's main function?  What about the runtime library's main function?

Comment: Another possibly useful approach would be to write your own injection DLL so that you can more easily debug the problem, to determine exactly what step in the DLL initialization is failing.  It should also be useful to determine whether a trivial DLL causes the crash, and if not, to try to narrow down action(s) in the DLL cause the crash.

Comment: Hi Harry - We do have version control, but it's 40 developers over a year so the changesets are quite massive.  Right now I'm comparing the settings of VS from the old project vs the new (we used VS 2010 for both).  This is crashing well before we get to our main function or even the runtime lib's main function.  I'll definitely try the trivial DLL that injects -- thanks :)

Comment: This is a classic sign of a pointer bug in your code.  Makes your app very sensitive to memory allocation order.

Comment: Hi Hans - Thanks, there's probably a great many of those. The app dates back 15 years, there's a lot of really messy legacy areas which do all kinds of uncouth things with pointers.  Any tips for how to track down a pointer bug in a case like this?  Seems like it may be a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @Hans: could it really be a pointer bug when the crash occurs before any of the user's code is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a fix.  I used Process Monitor to compare the order of DLL loading in versions with and without DLL injectors.  One thing that then struck me is the C++ DLL I have which loads .NET (via LoadLibrary) was being included first.  Because the CLR is such a large beast, I decided to try delay-loading that DLL and all .NET DLLs.  That's all it took - my problem has gone away.

So it's as Raymond Chen said -- the ordering is fragile.  If other people encounter this issue, I suggest just tweaking your DLL loading order.